# Thread constructor behaviour in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Test extends Thread {

     public void run() {

           System.out.println("done");
      }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

            Thread t = new Thread(new Program33());
            t.start();

     }
}
```

//java.lang.Thread class does not have any constructor that takes a Thread as an argument, then why does this program runs successfully.

Comment: _"//java.lang.Thread class does not have any constructor that takes a Thread as an argument,"_ and what is the constructor `Thread(Runnable target)` for ? Remember that a Thread is a Runnable

Comment: What is `Program33`? Perhaps, it implements `Runnable`?

Comment: @VictorSorokin, it is the name of my Program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread class have constructor that takes  Runnable

```
  public Thread(Runnable target)
```

and Thread implements Runnable.
You can see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: but my program extends Thread, it doesn't implement Runnable.

Comment: but The thread is implements Runnable so if your program extends something that implements Runnable its also in some way implements Runable..
if their is a constructor like public Thread (Object obj)
so you can put any object, although it not  explicit extends object..

Comment: I get it, thanks for helping. If u r free I also have one more question that I posted earlier, can u please help me with it. here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291626/how-to-put-composite-id-for-this-personpk-class

Answer (score 2):

`Thread` has a constructor that takes a single `Runnable` and the `Thread` class does implement the `Runnable` interface.

That constructor is getting invoked here.

Assuming that your `Programm33` either `extends Thread` or `implements Runnable`, your code will compile.

See [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: can that constructor that implements Runnable take a thread object as an argument.

Comment: @Aamir the `class` implements `Runnable`. A constructor cannot implement anything. Since a `Thread` **is-a** `Runnable`, `new Thread(Runnable r)` is equivalent of `new Thread(myPreviousThread)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable)) in [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) take take [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable)) as parameter:

```
public Thread(Runnable target)
```

As Thread implements [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable)), it's quite obvious that it will work.